# storing the value of GET variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, get, pagination

I have a search bar on the first page and the results are shown on the second page with pagination. The problem is the pagination isn't working with `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable.

what I meant is like when the form is submitted the url on second page changes to something like

`products.php?search=something` and I am able to see the results that show up.

However when I hit the next button of the pagination I get `undefined index search error` and the url changes to `products.php?page=2`

so is there any way that I can store the `$_GET['search'];` value so that I can use it when the page number changes?

```
  <form action="products.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <input type="Submit">
  </form>
```

products.php

```
  <?php
        /*
         * Connect to the database (Replacing the XXXXXX's with the correct details)
         */
        try
        {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
        /*
         * Get and/or set the page number we are on
         */
        if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        else
        {
            $page = 1;
        }


        /*
         * Set a few of the basic options for the class, replacing the URL with your own of course
         */
        $options = array(
            'results_per_page'              => 100,
            'url'                           => 'products.php?page=*VAR*',
            'db_handle'                     => $dbh
        );

        $q = $_GET['search'];
        /*
         * Create the pagination object
         */


        try

     {   

           $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT * FROM products where title LIKE '%$q%' order by id desc", $options);}

     catch(paginationException $e)
        {
            echo $e;
            exit();
        }


    if($paginate->success == true)
        {
            $paginate_result = $paginate->resultset->fetchAll();
            foreach($paginate_result as $row)
            {

                   echo $row['title'];
                   }

            ?>


         <?php echo "<li>"; //this is next and prev button for the pagination class if results exceed the limit. 
     echo $ball->links_html;
     echo "</li>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to something like this ...

```
<form action="products.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <input type="Submit">
  </form>
```

... and ...

```
   $options = array(
                'results_per_page'              => 100,
                'url'                           => 'products.php?search=' . urlencode($_GET['search']) . '&page=*VAR*',
                'db_handle'                     => $dbh
            );
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution would probably be to use a hidden field in your form:

```
<form action="products.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>">
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: he needs the search value in his pagination code not the search box.

Answer (score -1):

Try Session variables, they let you store it until the browser is closed(or you switch to another website maybe?) and store it across pages.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

The other alternative is cookies, which will let you store for just about as long as you want unless the user deletes their cookies.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php

Comment: don't do this if you are on page 4 of one search, then you do another search ... now your on page 4 again

Comment: As I understand it, all he wants to store is the value that was searched for, not the page number.  It may be easier to always get it as a GET variable instead of sometimes GET, sometimes SESSION but you definitely could store it in a session variable.  Basically, if there is a GET variable use it and store as a session variable.. otherwise, look for the session variable and use it.